# Attributes & Expressions - Create a Packing List Item Component

Tags: trailhead, aura-attribute

I'm new to Salesforce and stuck on a challenge on Trailhead.
Inside an Aura component, I am supposed to create a custom attribute.
This seems to be the first step, but it fails regardless.

My code:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c" required="true"/>
</aura:component>
```

Corresponding error:

```
Failed to save campingListItem.cmp: Invalid <aura:attribute>-Type: Camping_Item__c: Quelle
```

Cannot seem to find information on defining custom attributes in the Trailhead page or the developer documentation. Anyways, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you create the Camping Item object? You need to follow the steps in order.

Comment: No I did not, didn't see that. How do I create an object?

Comment: Setup > Object Manager > New. This should be in the trailhead somewhere. I think [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_prereqs) is what you need.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize I skipped over that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @sfdcfox:

I skipped over the 'Before You Begin' section. That covers creating Custom Fields:

- Go to Setup > Object Manager > New

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_prereqs